# Image carousel will not scroll when I have it displaying 4 images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a image carousel on a site I'm creating, it should have 8 images total however only show 4 at a time and scroll left to right with a click of a button. The scroll feature works until I set the widths of the images to fit 4 images then the scrolling completely stops functioning. If I leave it on 2 images (very stretched) it functions exactly as it should.

```
<div class="carousel-container">
            <div class="carousel-wrapper">
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo4.jpg" alt="Image 4">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo5.jpg" alt="Image 5">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo6.jpg" alt="Image 6">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo7.jpg" alt="Image 7">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/content/photo8.jpg" alt="Image 8">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-btn prev-btn">❮</div>
            <div class="carousel-btn next-btn">❯</div>
        </div>
```

```
.carousel-container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px; /* Set the desired height */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%; /* Make the wrapper take the full height of the container */
}

.carousel-item {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 12.5%; /* Ensure each item takes 25% of the wrapper's width */
    height: 100%; /* Make each item take the full height of the wrapper */
}

.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.carousel-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  }
.prev-btn {
    left: 0;
  }
.next-btn {
    right: 0;
  }
.carousel-btn:hover {
    background-color: #87CEEB;
  }
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("Script loaded!");

    // Get necessary elements
    const carouselWrapper = document.querySelector('.carousel-wrapper');
    const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
    const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
    const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');

    // Set the width and height of each carousel item
    const itemWidth = carouselWrapper.clientWidth / 4; // Show 4 items at a time
    const itemHeight = carouselWrapper.clientHeight;
    carouselItems.forEach(item => {
        item.style.width = `${itemWidth}px`;
        item.style.height = `${itemHeight}px`;
    });

    // Set the width of the carousel dynamically based on the number of items
    carouselWrapper.style.width = `${carouselItems.length * itemWidth}px`;

    // Function to scroll the carousel
    function scrollCarousel(direction) {
        const scrollAmount = itemWidth * direction;

        // Scroll the carousel
        carouselWrapper.scrollLeft += scrollAmount;

        // Check if reached the end and reset to the beginning or vice versa
        if (direction === 1 && carouselWrapper.scrollLeft + carouselWrapper.clientWidth >= carouselWrapper.scrollWidth) {
            carouselWrapper.scrollLeft = 0;
        } else if (direction === -1 && carouselWrapper.scrollLeft <= 0) {
            carouselWrapper.scrollLeft = carouselWrapper.scrollWidth - carouselWrapper.clientWidth;
        }
    }

    // Add click event listeners to buttons
    prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log("Previous button clicked");
        scrollCarousel(-1);
    });

    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log("Next button clicked");
        scrollCarousel(1);
    });
});
```

[Demo of it](https://jsfiddle.net/DamageWasTaken/q0tdsf9w/4/)

I have tried multiple widths.

Answer (score 0):

So, when you put `overflow: hidden` you are making it "unscrollable" meaning, your buttons won't work. I've added an extra `div`, as `carousel`, and made that scrollable so that your right button wouldn't move when the carousel is self scrolled. I also changed some of your script so copy and paste the whole thing in each section. Hope this helps.

Also, you probably don't want to be showing a scroll bar, understandable. So I've put in `CSS` to make it invisible.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        console.log("Script loaded!");

        // Get necessary elements
        const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
        const carouselWrapper = document.querySelector('.carousel-items-wrapper');
        const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
        const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
        const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');

        // Set the width and height of each carousel item
        const itemWidth = carouselWrapper.clientWidth / 4; // Show 4 items at a time
        const itemHeight = carouselWrapper.clientHeight;
        carouselItems.forEach(item => {
            item.style.width = `${itemWidth}px`;
            item.style.height = `${itemHeight}px`;
        });

        // Set the width of the carousel dynamically based on the number of items
        carouselWrapper.style.width = `${carouselItems.length * itemWidth}px`;

        // Function to scroll the carousel
        function scrollCarousel(direction) {
            const scrollAmount = itemWidth * direction;

            // Scroll the carousel
            carousel.scrollLeft += scrollAmount;

            // Check if reached the end and reset to the beginning or vice versa
            if (direction === 1 && carousel.scrollLeft + carousel.clientWidth >= carousel.scrollWidth) {
                carousel.scrollLeft = 0;
            }
            if (direction === -1 && carousel.scrollLeft <= 0) {
                carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth;
            }
        }

        // Add click event listeners to buttons
        prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log("Previous button clicked");
            scrollCarousel(-1);
        });

        nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log("Next button clicked");
            scrollCarousel(1);
        });
    });
```

```css
    .carousel-container {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .carousel {
        width: 100%;
            height: 400px; /* Set the desired height */
            overflow-x: scroll;
            scrollbar-color: green;
    }

    .carousel-items-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%; /* Make the wrapper take the full height of the container */
    }

    .carousel-item {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 12.5%; /* Ensure each item takes 25% of the wrapper's width */
        height: 100%; /* Make each item take the full height of the wrapper */
    }
    
    .carousel-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .carousel-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 24px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }
    .prev-btn {
        left: 0;
    }
    .next-btn {
        right: 0;
    }
    .carousel-btn:hover {
        background-color: #87CEEB;
    }
/* Style scroll bar to hide it */
    /* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: transparent; 
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
        <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-items-wrapper">
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/255/250" alt="Image 1">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/255/250" alt="Image 2">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/257" alt="Image 3">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/253" alt="Image 4">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/250" alt="Image 5">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/250" alt="Image 6">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/250" alt="Image 7">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://placekitten.com/250/253" alt="Image 8">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="carousel-btn prev-btn">❮</div>
        <div class="carousel-btn next-btn">❯</div>
    </div>
</div>
```